# Action with parameter in Control.BeginInvoke(

Tags: c#, action, anonymous-function

Sorry for the noobish question, my syntax is wrong and I cant understand why.

```
internal delegate void DoSomethingWithParam(MyObject localObjectToPassAsParam);
```

and I use it:

```
myControl.BeginInvoke(new FinishAddingEntitiesToFolderDelegate(FunctionNameWithSignatureAsDelegate), localObjectToPassAsParam);
```

This will call my function OK:

```
private void FunctionNameWithSignatureAsDelegate(MyObject localObjectToPassAsParam)
{
   Logger.Debug(localObjectToPassAsParam);
}
```

This works fine, when I try doing so with anonymous delegate it does not compile.

Where Am I suppose to put the parameter ?

```
myControl.BeginInvoke((Action<MyObject >)(() =>
{
   //I want to use my object here..
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried it this way?

```
myControl.BeginInvoke((localObjectToPassAsParam)=>
{
   // Your code here
}));
```

Let localObjectToPassAsParam be the instance of your object ;-) Please try and let me know, whether it worked in terms of type safety.